# Why does the string conflict with this union type?

Tags: typescript, react-native

I get a type error in `react-native` using `typescript` using the `borderStyle` property. The `borderStyle` property is declared as a union-type in react-natives' declaration file (`index.d.ts`). Used to flow I set the value in my style definitions simply with a string but now I get an error in typescript.

**Question:** How do I handle the style property of `borderStyle` the right way that I don't violate the typescript rule?

*My borderStyle property which causes the error:*

```
style: {
    borderStyle: 'solid',
},
```

*borderStyle is typed as:*

```
borderStyle?: "solid" | "dotted" | "dashed";
```

*Resulting error message using my style:*

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"solid" | "dotted" | "dashed" | undefined'
```

---

#### Update 1: How do I declare the styles in detail

1. I have a `common.styles.ts` file with common styles (that makes the error)

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import theme from './theme.styles';

export default {
    borders: {
        normal: {
            borderColor: '#E8E8E8',
            borderStyle: 'solid',
        },
        light: {
            borderColor: '#F1F1F1',
            borderStyle: 'solid',
        },
    },
};
```

2. I use these common styles in my style declaration file (`Component.styles.ts`) using a spread operator:

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import common from './../../../styles/common.styles';

export default StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        ...common.borders.normal,
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
    },
});
```

Comment: Can you share full section of style? How you declare your `style`?

Comment: @Isaac: I added the details in Update 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [referential integrity issue](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-typescript-breaks-referential-transparency-7a82c0345f2c) in typescript.
In this block:

```
style: {  borderStyle: 'solid'}
```

The type for `borderStyle` is string which is wider type than `"solid" | "dotted" | "dashed"`

Try

```
style: {  borderStyle: <"solid" | "dotted" | "dashed">'solid'}
```

To cast the string solid to the proper type.

Comment: To be clear the part about referential integrity is why you can assign it direvtly as an literal but not using a variable.

Answer (score 1):

try do this: `<View style={{  borderStyle: 'solid' }}/>`
i dont get any error in this code,i think maybe error is because of how importing style... 
styles in this 3 way dont get any error:

1. create style direct in view like line one
2. get **value** from somewhere (maybe props...) and set them to direct key of view style,you cant do this in styleSheet
3. create a const style object like this:

   `import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';`

then

```
const mstyle = StyleSheet.create({
      boredr: {
                 borderStyle: 'solid'
              }
})
```

and call it like this:

```
<View style={mstyle.border}/>
```